# Webpack-dev-server is not hot-reloading

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack-dev-server is not hot-reloading, instead it is reloading the entire page and refreshing the state.

My **webpack.config**

```
  entry: {
    "app": [
        "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000/",
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        "./src/index.js",
    ],
    "vendor": [
        "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000/",
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        "react", "react-router", "react-dom", "redux", "react-redux", "redux-logger", "redux-thunk"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: DEV ? 'js/app.bundle.js' : 'js/app.[chunkhash:6].js',
    publicPath:'http://localhost:3000/'
  },
```

**package.json**

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot --history-api-fallback --port 3000"
```

**src/index.js**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let container = document.getElementById(appName);

    if (!container) {
        container = document.createElement('div');
        container.id = appName;
        container.className = appName;
        document.body.appendChild(container);
    }

    render(<ProviderComponent />, container);

    if (module.hot) {
    // Whenever a new version of App.js is available
    module.hot.accept('./provider',  () => {
    // Require the new version and render it instead
        const NextApp = require('./provider').default
        console.log(NextApp);
        render(<NextApp />, container)
    })
    }
});
```

**provider.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import Routes from './routes.js';
import clientStore from './clientStore.js';

class ProviderComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={clientStore}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>{Routes}</Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default ProviderComponent;
```

After searching across the web, I came to know many people have faced a similar issue. I gave a second look to my code and it already contains all the solutions pointed out at different pages. And, I am not able to figure out if there is some other webpack internal intricacies that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues in the past using webpack-dev-server.

My solution was to add reload=true to the entry of the webpack config.

```
entry: {
"app": [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000&reload=true",
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    "./src/index.js",
],
```